# How can I get my visa again if my visa page gets torn from my passport?

Tags: uk

I have a UK visa, and I was supposed to start my journey on June 6 for a conference in the UK, but before that journey the page with the visa was torn out completely. After that I applied for a new passport.

Now I am invited again for another conference in the UK. So should I apply for a new visa or can I transfer my previous visa in my new passport? If I have to apply for a new visa, what are the chances of rejection? At this moment, can you suggest me what I should do to get the visa? It's very urgent for my career and life as well.

I am helpless at this point and looking forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: Note that there is a procedure by which you can [officially transfer UK visas between passports](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa) (for a fee.)  Do you still have the visa page from your old passport, or was that lost?

Comment: Edit out `If I have to apply for a new visa, what are the chances of rejection?` because nobody can answer that part of the question.

Comment: I went through the link but didn't find any option to add anything in my previous application. May be its not functional anymore. In this circumstances,  should I create a new application for the visa transfer? Can you tell me how can I apply for the visa transfer? In this  link, only I found the rate of visa transfer. Please help me out.

Comment: Dear Michael Seifert, And most of the part is lost.

Comment: I have got my answer, I need to apply for a new visa, there is no chance to transfer my previous visa into the new passport. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @ParomitaDas that should be an answer, not a comment.  A moderator converted it to a comment incorrectly.  Please repost it as an answer so it can be upvoted.  You should also accept it by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons.  Thanks.

Comment: If you can also include a description of how you came by that answer it will be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I communicated to the UK embassy through the email and I have got my answer, I have to apply for a new visa, there is no chance to transfer my previous visa into the new passport.

They advised me to apply for a fresh visa. My previous visa is invalid

FYI,I had to pay for that email.
Besides, I went to the visa processing office as there is no UK embassy center in my country, but they replied the same in this regard.

Comment: Yes, Willeke. They advised me to apply for a fresh visa. My previous visa is invalid 

Comment: I communicated to the UK embassy through the email and I had to pay for it, besides, went to the visa processing office as there is no UK embassy center in my country, but they replied the same in this regard.